# How to call default constructor of an abstract class in Java

Tags: java, constructor

I tried to research over this topic but could not find a clarity over this. Please help me in this.

Comment: Without any dirty magics, you cannot create an instance of abstract class.

Comment: You cannot instantiate an abstract class, but from a child-class, u can call the parent constructor with the super() method.

Comment: @Deepak luckily I know the dirty magic `MyAbstract  childObject= new MyChildClass();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use super() in your child class. You cannot create instance of abstract class(you might know that)

```
  abstract class Parent{
        Parent(){
            System.out.println("Parent contructor!");
        }
    }


    public class Child extends Parent{

        public Child() {
            super();
            System.out.println("Child contructor!");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new Child();
        }
    }
```

Even if you do not specify `super()` in `Child` class, still the parent class constructor will be called because `super()` will be put by compiler in default constructor of `Child` class while generating the .class. If you only have parameterized constructor in Parent class then you will have to explicitly call the parent class constructor by `super(..parameter)` in your child class constructor . Hope this helps!

Comment: Sanket D, I am good with super() and the fact that instance of abstract class can't be created. But my confusion with respect to your answer is that 'Parent()' having print statement should be default constructor, so as per your example default constructor can be defined in an abstract class.

Comment: default and parameterized constructor both can be defined in abstract class

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor of a child-class you can call

```
super(/*params if needed*/);
```

in order to call its parent's constructor

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
abstract class MyClass{ 
    int val;
    public MyClass( int val) {
        this.val= val;
    }

}

class Test extends MyClass{
    public Test () {
        super(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: mir, I believe MyClass is a parametrized constructor  within Abstract class.

Comment: @Deepak  there is no default  constructor in the parent abstract class, the constructor used in subclass must explicitly call the parent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

While you may not call upon a default constructor for an Abastract class, you can invoke the default constructor for the sub-class that embodies your abstract class.

For example:

```
 abstract class Animal {

      public Animal (){ ... }

      abstract public String sound();
 }


 class Horse extends Animal{

    public Horse(){ 
        super()
    }

    @Override 
    public String sound(){ 
        return "neigh";
    }
 }

 class Dog extends Animal{

    public Dog(){ 
        super()
    }

    @Override 
    public String sound(){ 
        return "woof";
    }
 }
```

It is not directly possible to make a new Animal. You can make new `Dog`-s and `Horse`-s with annomyously for (common) Type `Animal` example:

```
 public Animal makeAnimals( Animal existingCreature ) 
     throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
 {
     return existingCreature.getClass.newInstance();
 }
```

Will make a new instance of the concrete class you provided:

```
 Dog   fido  = new Dog();
 Horse hack  = new Horse();

 Dog   puppy = makeAnimals( fido );   //  new uninitialised Dog   instance
 Horse foal  = makeAnimals( hack );   //  new uninitialised Horse instance
```

Alternatively you can make an annomyous instance

```
Animal parrot = new Animal() {

    @Override 
    public String sound(){ 
        return "squawk";
    }
}
```

As a way to make new animal types.  If you were doing something for real like Animals it would probably be better to make a `Parot` subclass.